# Snowpack with local npm packages

Tags: snowpack

We have problem to run snowpack with our package structure.

Our structure:

```
adapters
app
core
presentation
```

Each package contains typescript and all are used in the `app` package.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@project/adapters": "file:../../adapters",
    "@project/core": "file:../../core",
    "@project/presentation": "file:../../presentation",
}
```

I get the error `Dependency Install Error: Package "@project/adapters/src/repositories/GradeFeedRepositoryImpl" not found. Have you installed it?`

How do I need to configure snowpack, web pack, babel, ... to run this?

Answer (score 0):

I have had success with packing modules (using: `npm pack /path/to/module` from the root of the module's folder) and adding the tarball to my `package.json` from a folder within the repo. e.g.,

```
"dependencies": {
...

   "adapters": "file:packs/adapters-1.0.0.tgz"

...
}
```

---

Another option, see if making this edit to your `snowpack.config.js` file helps:

```
packageOptions: {
    external: [
        "@projects/adapters"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you just build the module and use it with link protocol in the main package.json?

Comment: I think that will depend on how you deploy your application. For example for one of my repos, I copy and build the app in a dockerfile. With a relative link, the module will be missing (as it lives in its own repo), so I don't believe relative links will work in all deployment environments.